# Как обновлять виджет после нажатия кнопки в tkinter

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

Есть микропрограмма которая должна печатать примеры в количестве указанном из строки ввода. Но после каждого последующего нажатия на кнопку мне нужно чтобы предыдущий текст очищался и на его место встал другой

```
from tkinter import *
from great6 import * #отдельный файл с вызываемыми функциями

class Block:
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.e = Entry(width=20)
        self.b = Button(text="Пример",bg="lightgrey")
        self.l = Label(bg="grey", fg="white", width=20)
        self.out = []
        self.e.focus_set()
        self.e.pack()
        self.b.pack()
        self.l.pack()

    def setFun(self, func):
        self.b['command'] = eval('self.' + func)

    def strout(self):
        s = self.e.get()
        self.e.delete(0,'end')
        k = 1
        if s.isalnum():
            while int(s) >= 1:
                self.out.append((str(k) + ')' + sqr_eq()) + '=')
                s = int(s) - 1
                k += 1
        self.l.config(text='\n '.join(self.out))


root = Tk()
root.title('Mathgen')
first_block = Block(root)
first_block.setFun('strsort')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то решилось само после добавления второй кнопки

```
from tkinter import *

from great6 import *


class Block:
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.e = Entry(width=20)
        self.beq = Button(text="квадратное уравнение", bg="lightgrey")
        self.l = Label(bg="grey", fg="white", width=20)
        self.l2 = Label(bg="grey", fg="white", width=20)
        self.bsum = Button(text="квадрат суммы", bg="lightgrey")
        self.out = []

        self.e.focus_set()
        self.e.pack()
        self.beq.pack()
        self.bsum.pack()
        self.l.pack()
        self.l2.pack()

    def b_eq(self, func):
        self.beq['command'] = eval('self.' + func)

    def b_sum(self, func):
        self.bsum['command'] = eval('self.' + func)

    def eqout(self):
        s = self.e.get()
        self.e.delete(0, 'end')

        self.out = []
        self.l.config(text='')

        k = 1
        if s.isalnum():
            while int(s) >= 1:
                self.out.append((str(k) + ')' + sqr_eq()) + '=')
                s = int(s) - 1
                k += 1
        self.l.config(text='\n '.join(self.out))

    def sumout(self):
        s = self.e.get()
        self.e.delete(0, 'end')

        self.out = []
        self.l2.config(text='')

        k = 1
        if s.isalnum():
            while int(s) >= 1:
                self.out.append((str(k) + ')' + sqr_sum()) + '=')
                s = int(s) - 1
                k += 1
        self.l2.config(text='\n '.join(self.out))


root = Tk()

root.title('Mathgen')
first_block = Block(root)

first_block.b_eq('eqout')
first_block.b_sum('sumout')

root.mainloop()
```